# How to create a custom seekTo player interface with vimeo embedded code?

Tags: javascript, php, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have a site with a vimeo video player that I am embedding using Vimeo's PHP example.

External control buttons on the site need to seek to different "tracks" inside the Vimeo video, that is inside an iframe.

Comment: If you're trying to [self-answer a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), note that you should still provide **a separate question and answer**, both of which should be up to the site quality standards, not just drop everything into the question box.

Comment: Was that so difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `postMessage` to pass JSON string data back to the iframe.

```
function skipTo(time) {
    var f = jQuery("#vid_player iframe");
    var url = f.attr('src');
    var data = {method: "seekTo", value: time};
    f[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
}
```

See API documentation that was somewhat helpful, but at least has a list of other methods you may need to utilize: http://api-portal.anypoint.mulesoft.com/vimeo/api/vimeo-javascript-api/docs/reference